# Skip field when use REPLACE INTO

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = REPLACE INTO `table` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`) VALUES (:id, :name, :created_at);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name']);
$stmt->bindValue(':created_at', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$stmt->execute();
```

`REPLACE INTO` will detect if primary key exist then update it, if not add a new record, it's really convenient to do the check by itself, but some filed should not be update again for example `create_at`, `created_at` should keep the time when first time created the data, any way to skip file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). It gives you more control over the update part. (also replace will delete your row and create a new one which can give problems using constrains)

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `name`, `created_at`) VALUES (:id, :name, :created_at) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = :name';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name']);
$stmt->bindValue(':created_at', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$stmt->execute();
```